# Android Accessibility Service Unit Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, service, automated-tests, accessibility

I am creating an Accessibility Service.

Currently the application just Overrides the onAccessibilityEvent method, and puts into a JSON object some of the event data.  When I start the service, and run another application, the service does capture and log the events that occur on the other app.

How do you unit test an accessibility service>

For example can I set up Unit Tests in my Accessibility Service to test if particular buttons on another app are clicked and control that programmatically?